# RewriteRule problem with Proxy balancer Apache

Tags: node.js, apache, mod-rewrite, webserver, reverse-proxy

I configured an apache web server as a reverse proxy to my nodejs application.
This is my apache conf:

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyRequests Off
    ServerName mywebsite.com
    ServerAlias www.mywebsite.com

    <Location /custom/>
        ProxyPass http://localhost:8055/
        ProxyPassReverse http://localhost:8055/

        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteRule ^(.*)\[eq\](.*)$ $1$2 [NE,NC,L]
        RewriteRule ^(.*)%5Beq%5D(.*)$ $1$2 [NC,L]
    </Location>

    RedirectPermanent /custom https://mywebsite.com/custom/
    RedirectPermanent / https://mywebsite.com/custom/

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/mywebsite.com/fullchain.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/mywebsite.com/privkey.pem
    Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

For compatibility I needed to rewrite some url and I used the RewriteRule. This is an example of rewriting:

`https://mywebsite.com/custom/items?[test][eq]=1&anothertest=2` *become* `https://mywebsite.com/custom/items?[test]=1&anothertest=2`

With the configuration above everithing works fine.

I decided to create another instance of my nodejs to load balancing the requestes. So I modified my apache conf to this:

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>
    <Proxy balancer://my-cluster>
        BalancerMember http://localhost:8055
        BalancerMember http://localhost:8056
        ProxySet lbmethod=bytraffic
    </Proxy>
    
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyRequests Off
    ServerName mywebsite.com
    ServerAlias www.mywebsite.com

    <Location /custom/>
        ProxyPass balancer://my-cluster/
        ProxyPassReverse balancer://my-cluster/

        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteRule ^(.*)\[eq\](.*)$ $1$2 [NE,NC,L]
        RewriteRule ^(.*)%5Beq%5D(.*)$ $1$2 [NC,L]
    </Location>

    RedirectPermanent /custom https://mywebsite.com/custom/
    RedirectPermanent / https://mywebsite.com/custom/

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/mywebsite.com/fullchain.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/mywebsite.com/privkey.pem
    Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

With this configuration everything works fine, execept for rewrited urls that are wrong.

Using the same example previously defined:

`https://mywebsite.com/custom/items?[test][eq]=1&anothertest=2` *become* `https://mywebsite.com/custom/items?[test]=1&anothertest=2/custom/items`

Can you help me to find the solution?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "With the configuration above everithing works fine." - except that the first config would **not** rewrite the request as stated either. (?) For a couple of reasons... the `RewriteRule` _pattern_ does not match the query string (in your example URL, `[eq]` is part of the query string). Your example URL is HTTP, whereas your vHost is for HTTPS.

Comment: Sorry, hi edited the examples with https. I confirm you that the first conf work and the [eq] is correctly removed.